# MS Word SaveAs dialogbox shows up after calling SaveAs method with a filename

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

in my `C#` application, I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` to convert Rtf to Xml.

```
string tmpWordFullname = Path.GetTempFileName();
string fileContents = myRtfText2Convert;
File.WriteAllText(tmpWordFullname, fileContents);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var currentDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(tmpWordFullname);
currentDoc.Activate();

string newTempName = Path.GetDirectoryName(tmpWordFullname) + "\\" +
                       Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tmpWordFullname) + "1.xml";

currentDoc.SaveAs(newTempName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXML);
```

It works fine on `Office 2007`, but in later versions, the saveas dialog box pops up even though I've given a name and user has to enter a new name which won't be the one I've set in `newTempName`.

Event knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

wordApp.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone; // wordApp.DisplayAlerts =false;

Tested and works perfectly

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string tmpWordFullname = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
    string fileContents = "test test test";
    File.WriteAllText(tmpWordFullname, fileContents);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    wordApp.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
    var currentDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(tmpWordFullname);
    currentDoc.Activate();

    string newTempName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(tmpWordFullname) + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tmpWordFullname) + "1.xml";

    currentDoc.SaveAs(newTempName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXML);
}
```

Comment: It's `wordApp.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;` and it's not working anyways.

Comment: It doesn't work on some particular files in Office 2010 and later versions